# An activex control on this page might be unsafe

Tags: activex

I created a com component in C#, which I registered by using Regasm. I am able now to use this in IE by using ActiveXObject(...). However this only works when I change my IE security settings and allow to run unsigned activex controls, in which case I get the message:

> An ActiveX control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want to allow this interaction?

I always want IE to allow this interaction without the prompt. Does anybody know how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ActiveX control must implement the IObjectSafety interface in order for IE to stop showing the "unsafe?" prompt.  I did this several years ago for a VB6 ActiveX control. In the 5th step of [This page](http://www.olavaukan.com/2010/08/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/) is shown how to do it in .Net.

Comment: Does this get applied to the web form or the win form? Can the IObjectSafety be implemented without the ActiveX page?

Comment: I would assume "no".  I have only seen it with ActiveX controls.

Comment: @David: Yes, I saw it. Actually, the problem is in IE settings in my case. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

I have already faced this problem.After long walk i have solved this problem.In your activeX class simply inherit IObjectSafety class.See the image bellow :
[image]

IObjectSafety Class given bellow:

```
 [ComImport, GuidAttribute("CB5BDC81-93C1-11CF-8F20-00805F2CD064")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IObjectSafety
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref int pdwSupportedOptions,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref int pdwEnabledOptions);

    [PreserveSig()]
    int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwOptionSetMask,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwEnabledOptions);
}
public class IObjectSafetyImpl : IObjectSafety
 {
     private const string _IID_IDispatch = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}";
     private const string _IID_IDispatchEx = "{a6ef9860-c720-11d0-9337-00a0c90dcaa9}";
     private const string _IID_IPersistStorage = "{0000010A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}";
     private const string _IID_IPersistStream = "{00000109-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}";
     private const string _IID_IPersistPropertyBag = "{37D84F60-42CB-11CE-8135-00AA004BB851}";

     private const int INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER = 0x00000001;
     private const int INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA = 0x00000002;
     private const int _OK = 0;
     private const int _FAIL = unchecked((int)0x80004005);
     private const int _NOINTERFACE = unchecked((int)0x80004002);

     private bool _fSafeForScripting = true;
     private bool _fSafeForInitializing = true;

     public int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, ref int pdwSupportedOptions, ref int pdwEnabledOptions)
     {
         int Result = _FAIL;

         string strGUID = riid.ToString("B");
         pdwSupportedOptions = INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
         switch (strGUID)
         {
             case _IID_IDispatch:
             case _IID_IDispatchEx:
                 Result = _OK;
                 pdwEnabledOptions = 0;
                 if (_fSafeForScripting == true)
                     pdwEnabledOptions = INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER;
                 break;
             case _IID_IPersistStorage:
             case _IID_IPersistStream:
             case _IID_IPersistPropertyBag:
                 Result = _OK;
                 pdwEnabledOptions = 0;
                 if (_fSafeForInitializing == true)
                     pdwEnabledOptions = INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
                 break;
             default:
                 Result = _NOINTERFACE;
                 break;
         }

         return Result;
     }

     public int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions)
     {
         int Result = _FAIL;

         string strGUID = riid.ToString("B");
         switch (strGUID)
         {
             case _IID_IDispatch:
             case _IID_IDispatchEx:
                 if (((dwEnabledOptions & dwOptionSetMask) == INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER) &&
                      (_fSafeForScripting == true))
                     Result = _OK;
                 break;
             case _IID_IPersistStorage:
             case _IID_IPersistStream:
             case _IID_IPersistPropertyBag:
                 if (((dwEnabledOptions & dwOptionSetMask) == INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA) &&
                      (_fSafeForInitializing == true))
                     Result = _OK;
                 break;
             default:
                 Result = _NOINTERFACE;
                 break;
         }

         return Result;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a .reg file to modify the registry key like this:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0]
"1201"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0]
"1201"=dword:00000000

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with the help of this answer it was possible to solve the question, the answer to which I was looking for a week

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Start -> Run -> regedit
> 2. Go to
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVer
>      sion\Internet Settings\Zones\0
> 3. Doubleclick 1201 and change the value to 0 (it was
>      probably 1)
> 4. Close Registry Editor

Comment: Can this be run in a script?

Comment: @clerktech in which script? if in ActiveX it is impossible without warning

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the sites trust level to full.

Tools->Internet Options->Security->Trusted Sites->Sites button

Comment: I already added the site as to my trusted list. I still get the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

As for signing the ActiveX see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364(VS.85).aspx).  However you will still have to allow the ActiveX (it'll just show you as the author).  See Ryan's answer for how to allow the ActiveX for this site.

Comment: I don't mind allowing the activex control, however if I keep getting the prompt then will become annoying. The control will be used only on our intranet anyways. I will see if signing helps.